# How do I display all document as objects from firestore database, with given filters retrieved from user input (Flutter/Dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

Hi I'm a student at uni and im working on a project using Flutter/Dart with Firebase.

The idea of the web app is to do a search on the Firestore database for available donors stored in the database and search for them by filtering by 'Blood Type', 'Gender' and retrieving them and displaying them in the web app.

[This section of the GUI is used to set the filters by the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH1Cs.png)

and I've wrapped this in a SingleChildScrollView so I can display the records below.

[I want to display the results when clickingthe 'Find Match' button. Within the try block is the implementation for this will go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMw4Y.png)

I'm trying to get all documents within a collection that is filtered with given user inputs which will return the documents and display them accordingly below the 'Find Match' button, I'm quite new to dart and firestore so I'm really struggling to get this sorted.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please post your code inline and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the user picks a combination of Gender = 'M' and BloodType = 'A. The following code block should query the firestore database using the filters

```
QuerySnapshot querySnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('donors')
    .where('gender', isEqualTo: 'M')
    .where('blood_type', isEqualTo: 'A')
    .get();
```

The filtered firestore documents can be retrieved using

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = querySnap.docs;
```

Take a look at the [documentation here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying) on the FlutterFire site for more information

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulRahman consider marking it as the answer then?